# Azure Mobile service(push notification)

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am working on Azure mobile service push notification and I am trying to send push notification on particular registration id. I have following script, can somebody tell me how can I update this JavaScript so it works fine:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {

   var push = request.service.push;       
   var token="APA91bG7pOV2jLiSiSujNS4Gg_Q##################";
   var mes = "Hellooooo";
   var payload = '{"data":{"message" : "Testing"}}';

   push.gcm.send(null,payload,{
        success: function(pushResponse) {
            console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse, payload);
            request.respond();
            },              
        error: function (pushResponse) {
            console.log("Error Sending push:", pushResponse);
            request.respond(500, { error: pushResponse });
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I hope this will be helpful to you, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-android-get-started-push/

Comment: it gives invalid payload eror

Comment: where do i pass registration id for sending push notification on that device?

Comment: Might be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278608/receive-wns-push-notfication-on-windows-phone-silverlight-8-1?noredirect=1#comment59376783_30278608